# Objective-C 'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'SegueIdentifier'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have this error here:

```
'Could not find a navigation controller for segue 'SegueIdentifier'. Push segues can only be used when the source controller is managed by an instance of UINavigationController.'
```

For this line of code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier: @"SegueIdentifier" sender: self];


}
```

I dont understand because I do have my segue in the storyboard to a UINavigation Controller....Please help.

Comment: What are you segueing from?  If your segue type is push but your current, source, view controller isn't managed by a UINavigationController then you will get this error

Comment: I am segueing from a UIViewController

Comment: Then  you can't use a `push` segue (which is deprecated anyway).  You will either need to use `show` `modal` or `replace`

Comment: replaced it with modal and it worked. Thanks @Paulw11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use a `push` segue if your source view controller is already managed by a UINavigationController.  If it isn't then you need to use a segue such as `modal` or `replace`.  The recommended approach is to use a `show` adaptive segue as this will work correctly regardless of whether your source is managed by a UINavigationController or not.